# foreach in foreach multiple dimensional

Tags: php, loops, foreach, duplicates

I'd like to know how to avoid dupplicate of element while using a foreach in foreach with multidimensional array ?

The first level of my array can have several item (here's just 2, but maybe I can have 7 level). I've a lot trouble with this. Then this ID is going to be used as a parameter in a sql request, but this is another story.

This is my array :

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                        )
                )
        )
```

This is my foreach loop :

```
foreach($dataListe as $listeDiff){
            foreach($listeDiff as $$item){
                // echo $item[0].'<br />';
                echo "<pre>".print_r($item, true)."</pre>";
            }
        }
```

Result :

```
        Array
(
    [id] => 10
)

Array
(
    [id] => 11
)

Array
(
    [id] => 12
)

Array
(
    [id] => 11
)

Array
(
    [id] => 12
)
```

Wanted :

```
        Array
(
    [id] => 10
)

Array
(
    [id] => 11
)

Array
(
    [id] => 12
)
```

Comment: Just do `array_unique` on the result, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_unique()

```
$result = [];
foreach($dataListe as $listeDiff){
   $result[] = $listeDiff;        
}
$result = array_unique($result);
```

Comment: This seems to be the good answer, but I have array( array[0] (array[0] ... array[1]...))). Is it possible to get ride of the first level of array ? **EDIT** my bad, forget to do the foreach on $result. Thanks !

Comment: Well, it's not working if I have more than 2 array in the first level (the last is missing, but the first and the second one are showing)

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
$dataListe = array(
    array(array('id'=>10),array('id'=>20),array('id'=>20),array('id'=>10),array('id'=>20)),
    array(array('id'=>10),array('id'=>30),array('id'=>20),array('id'=>10),array('id'=>20))
    );

$result = array();
foreach($dataListe as $listeDiff){
    foreach($listeDiff as $item){
            if(!(in_array($item, $result))){
               $result[] = $item;
               echo "<pre>".print_r($item, true)."</pre>";
            }

    }   
}
```

sample out put

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 20
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 30
    )

)
```

Comment: Can you share your array ?  It's simple you need keep elements which are allready travellesed

Comment: See my first post, the array is the same than "result"